# How to use dark mode from Tailwind 3 in Angular 13 style components?

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

In Angular style component I create a certain class in a component, like this

```
// app.component.scss
.class{
    @apply dark:text-red-500 dark:bg-green-700 text-green-700 bg-red-500 px-5;
}
```

The problem is, that Angular doesn't recognise the main `body` or `html` when I apply dark mode... Is there any method to use dark mode in Angular from a class( using media it works well)? Is there any settings I have missed?

```
//tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  darkMode: "class",
  plugins: [
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, they do advise to add the `dark`class in the html or body tag.
However, that's more a suggestion than anything else.

The only thing necessary to use the dark mode is to have a parent node having this dark class.

#### What you can do

Wrapping your `<router-outlet>` in your app-component html with a custom div with you class :

```html
<div class="dark">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

#### What I usually do

Wrapping my `<router-outlet>` by a custom div having an id, let's say `<div id="themeHandler">` and create a service handling if you use or not the dark mode by injecting the dark class to my div selecting it in my service and then add or remove this class :

```js
const themeHandler = document.getElementById('themeHandler');

/// Whatever condition to add the dark class
themeHandler.classList.add('dark');

// Whatever condition to remove the dark class
themeHandler.classList.remove('dark');
```